# How to retrive data in complex string using regex and grouping?

Tags: c#, regex, string

This text is a query result of a old system in an educational institution which needs to be parses and inserted in new SQL database.

```
1- DX 1203 /FA D0 R0   AM02XXL RAVT 1200   1330   UNQ 0 TT   Y                
             H0 QB KA MC G0 O0 ZT N0 L1 EA RA TB BB                              
      TEST MAY 2001 AND RESULT SEND TO ANALYS UNIT
   ...REGISTERED BY USER021/AMIN SARVI/79/02/01...                     
2  D0 2743 /FB D1 R1   PM12XLL RAFT 1000   1000   UNP 0 TS   Y                
             HX QX KA MX GX OX ZX NZ L1 EA R1 TB B0                              
      TEST MAY 2001 AND RESULT SEND TO ANALYS UNIT
3  DX 1151 /FA DX RX   AM02XLL RAVT 1200   1130   UNP 0 TS   N                
             HA QC KX MA GA OA Z0 N0 L0 E0 R0 TX BX                              
      TEST MAY 2001 AND RESULT SEND TO ANALYS UNIT(FAILED UNDER C)
   ...REGISTERED BY USER021/AMIN SARVI/79/02/12...  
4+ DA 2081 /FX DX RX   AM22XXL RAET 1200   1330   UNQ 0 SS   N                
             H0 QB KB MA GD OD Z0 NX L0 EA R0 T0 B0                              
      TEST MAY 2001 AND RESULT SEND TO ANALYS UNIT
   ...REGISTERED BY USER083/NAHID NAVABI/78/11/21...
```

We want to parse this `string` with RegEx and grouping in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), but for any entity exists one or two lines of description.
We succeeded in retrieving the original information, but we could not recover those lines.

Regex pattern:

```
((?<rownumber>[1-9])(\-|\+|\*|\s)\s*(?<unitCode>\w\w)\s*(?<studentCode>\d+)\s/(?<codeScore>(\w\w\s)+)\s*(?<time>\w\w\d\d\w\w\w)\s*(?<testCode>\w\w)(?<testState>\w\w)\s*(?<starttime>\d\d\d\d)\s*(?<endtime>\d\d\d\d)(?<addedTime>(\s|\+\d))\s*(?<commit>\w\w\w)\s*(?<retry>\d)\s*(?<equ>\w+)\s*(?<active>\w)\s*(?<codeScore1>(\w\w\s+)*))+
```

A test case can be found here: [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester)

Comment: Provide expected output please

Comment: @SergeyKhalitov Thanks to your reply, you can test data and pattern in [regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester) which show expected result in below of it(in table tab). Only doesn't any data about description and these data is important to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<rownumber>[1-9])([-+*\s])\s*(?<unitCode>\w\w)\s*(?<studentCode>\d+)\s\/(?<codeScore>(\w\w\s)+)\s*(?<time>\w\w\d\d\w\w\w)\s*((?<testCode>\w\w)(?<testState>\w\w?)\s*(?<starttime>\d\d\d\d)\s*(?<endtime>\d\d\d\d)(?<addedTime>(\s|\+\d))\s*(?<commit>\w\w\w)\s*(?<retry>\d)\s*(?<equ>\w+)\s*(?<active>\w)\s*(?<codeScore1>(\w\w\s+)*)\s*)+(?<comments>(\r?\n\s+[^\r\n]*)+)
```

Something like this?

Basically, I fixed up the original regex so it matched your sample data (testCode and testState cannot be four characters combined, since there are only three characters there), then added `(?<comments>(\r\n\s+[^\r\n]*)*)` to the end. That matches any sequences of linebreaks, indentation, then comments.

This assumes that the first data line won't begin with a space.

See it in action here (regexstorm site won't let me link to it very well): https://regex101.com/r/WkTyP0/2

Comment: Thanks to your reply. I didn't see any matched data in this link: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WkTyP0/1). Can you modify it with new data in my question?

Comment: It's perfect. Only modify this link in your response: https://regex101.com/r/WkTyP0/1